# stanford corenlp 3.3.1 language support

Tags: stanford-nlp

I'm starting to use coreNLP library 3.3.1 to analyze italian text documents. Have anybody tried to run a language other than English ? Did you find the models needed to train the algoritmhs ?
Thanks

Carlo

Comment: Hi Carlo, I'm also trying to use coreNLP on Italian since some times... could we join the effort? :-)

Comment: Did you achieve some good results? I'm Italian too and I'm interested in this topic

Answer (score 3):

At the moment, beyond English, we only package models for Chinese (see http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml#History), but people have also successfully used the German and French models that we distribute with the Stanford Parser, Stanford NER, or the Stanford POS Tagger inside CoreNLP. For Italian, you'd need annotated data available to train your own models. There are some treebanks available for Italian and the Stanford Parser has been trained for Italian. For info on resources for Italian, see: http://aclweb.org/aclwiki/index.php?title=Resources_for_Italian#Treebanks.